# How to process different columns in a data stream by different programs in Shell?

Tags: shell

Suppose that I have a stream, which contains three columns of data with `\t` as separator.

To process data in the stream, the later two columns are required to be handled by `prog1`, while the first column together with the output of `prog1` (1 column) will then be handled by `prog2`.

- `prog1`: read data (two columns) from stdin, and write its output to stdout.
- `prog2`: read data (two columns; one from the original stream, and another from the output of `prog1`) from stdin, and write its output to stdout.

With the consideration that both `prog1` and `prog2` cost much time while launching, repeatedly starting programs is not acceptable. Hence the following snippet does not really solve the problem:

```sh
IFS='\t'  # C-v tab
while read c0 c1 c2; do
  paste <(echo ${c0}) <(echo -e"${c1}\t${c2}" | prog1) | prog2
done </dev/stdin
```

Any clues or hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Right general idea, wrong execution. Move the `paste` to top-level.

Comment: The trickiest thing here is needing to tee out separate copies of stdin; that may call for a named FIFO.

Comment: Hi @CharlesDuffy, thanks for your comments. Would you please provide more details? I'm not sure how to do it...

Comment: When I have a full and complete answer, I'll add it as an answer rather than as a comment; takes a minute to write up and test. BTW, what operating system are you on? Can I assume GNU tools?

Comment: (though "and test" isn't possible here since `prog1` and `prog2` aren't provided, or stubbed out with test functions; this question's code thus isn't in the form of a [mre]; similarly, the question _implies_ that `prog1` can be streamed through, but never explicitly states this)

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy! It's the first time that I know the "named pipe". It helps a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Something along the following?

```
# create a temporary fifo
fifo=$(mktemp -u)
mkfifo "$fifo"
# split and get first column
tee >(cut -f1 >"$fifo") |
  # extract 2,3 column and pass to prog1
  cut -f2,3 | prog1 |
  # join with first column
  paste "$fifo" - |
  prog2
```

Comment: Thanks Kamil, this is really a nice answer! The combined using of named fifo pipe and anonymous pipe is exactly what I'm searching for.

Answer (score 1):

Creating named FIFOs lets us use `tee` to make multiple copies of the stdout stream, each of which can be fed as stdin to a separate independent loop -- letting `paste` live at the top level.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# create a temporary directory for our FIFOs, delete it when the script exits
tempdir=$(mktemp -t -d tempdir.XXXXXX) || exit
die() { rc=$?; rm -rf "$tempdir"; exit "$rc"; }
trap die EXIT

# create FIFOs in that temporary directory, start a background copy of tee
# ...to copy stdin into them.
mkfifo "$tempdir"/stdin{1,2}
tee "$tempdir/stdin1" >"$tempdir/stdin2" & tee_pid=$!
exec </dev/null # stdin is for tee, not us

# Run just one copy of paste, starting the while read loops as child processes
paste \
  <(while read c0 c1 c2; do echo "$c0"; done <"$tempdir/stdin1") \
  <(while read c0 c1 c2; do
      printf '%s\t%s\n' "$c1" "$c2"
    done <"$tempdir/stdin2" | prog1) \
  | prog2
```

Note that the `while read` loops are not particularly efficient -- they'd be better replaced with `awk` invocations -- but the expectation is that you'll be inserting your known-good code in place of them.

Using `echo -e` has unfortunate side effects -- for example, it would corrupt literal backslashes in your data, and also doesn't work as-intended with POSIX-standardized versions of `echo` (or even in bash's own `echo`, when running with optional runtime flags that make it strictly POSIX-compliant); using `printf` instead [avoids a great deal of trouble](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/3113).

Comment: Upvote for the idea to use named fifo pipe and the complete solution around it.